# Jsf 2.0 Custom Tags With Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I've created a panel (Refer - [Help on JSF 2.0 Custom Components and Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329070/help-on-jsf-2-0-custom-components-and-primefaces)) according to my earlier post, using custom component from back end, and have populated tags to the panel like inputtext,listbox,dropdown menu,selectoneradio. How do I save these values on button click? I've nothing to do on the view - (front end) All the processing has to be done at the back end. An example for the same would be very helpful.

This is what I've done -

```
private Panel myPanel;

public Panel getMyPanel() {
    return myPanel;
}

public void setMyPanel(Panel myPanel) {
    this.myPanel = myPanel;

    if (myPanel.getChildCount() <= 1) {
        InputText input = new InputText();
        input.setValue("my dynamic text");
        myPanel.getChildren().add(input);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not understand may be you could page some code from faces(xhtml).You can just use a backing bean to holde the values eg.#{person.name} etc

Comment: I've added What I've done. How do I now save the values i insert into the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give all dynamically created `UIForm`, `UIInput` and `UICommand` components a **fixed** ID.

```
input.setId("someId");
// ...
```

Otherwise JSF can't find them in the view state to process the submitted values.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? Binding the input component to a model value? Use `setValueExpression()` with a `#{bean.value}` instead of `setValue()`

Comment: I've a Save button. So on click of that button I've to bind the values to the backingbean.

Comment: Yes, use `input.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression)`. You only need to ensure that there's a `<h:form>` as parent.